# ConnectionString property has not been initialized IN ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me solving this problem:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

I'm new to ASP.NET.

I'm trying to display the username after log in in e `Label1.Text`. But when I run the code, it shows this error... it also shows

> INVALID OPERATION EXCEPTION WAS UNHANDLED

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Botswna_Centralized_Health_Card_System.healthcareOfficerLogins
{
    public partial class healthcareOfficerLogins : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["hospital_name"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/hospital_login/hospital_login.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BOW-PC\\BOW;Initial Catalog= BCHCS;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();

                showdata();
            }
        }

        public void showdata()
        {
            cmd.CommandText="select * from hospitallogins where hospital_Name='" + Session["hospital_Name"]+ "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            sda.Fill(ds);
            Label1.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hospital_Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Are you sure that this is the code that triggers the error?

Comment: For sure that is not the line that triggers the error.

Comment: Sorry i edited the code ...i'v added the showdata() method ...the  sda.Fill(ds); is the line that triggers the error

Comment: There are two "SqlConnection con" declaration. Global an local

Comment: i hav removed the local sqlConnection con Declaration ...but still having the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 different instances of `SqlConnection`, both of them named `con`.

The first is declared in your class:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
```

The second is declared inside of `Page_Load`:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BOW-PC\\BOW;Initial Catalog= BCHCS;Integrated Security=True");
```

When you call `showdata()`, you are using the first instance, which has not been initialized.

You really should refactor this to use a single connection. Also, to ensure you don't have any resource leaks, it is important to use a using block on `SqlConnection` or call `Dispose` in a finally block.

```
using (con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BOW-PC\\BOW;Initial Catalog= BCHCS;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();

    showdata();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working ...i managed to display a user's name after logging in ... i did use a using block on sqlConnection as you mentioned and worked ...thank you very much